# I recently dual booted my windows with Ubuntu. No WiFi networks are visible and WiFi settings are non existent

Tags: networking, 16.04, dual-boot, wireless, broadcom

I had Windows 10 on my machine and WiFi used to work fine. A few days ago, I dual booted it with Ubuntu 16.04. The WiFi continues to work in Windows but when I am using Ubuntu, I can't see any available WiFi networks or WiFi settings or anything else of the sort. I tried going to the additional drivers option and applying the Broadcom drive but even that didn't solve the problem. What should I do to get my WiFi working?

Output of lspci -knn | grep Net -A2

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [11ad:6605]
    Kernel modules: wl
```

When I did what was suggested in the linked answer, this happened:

```
 sudo dpkg -i *.deb

dpkg: warning: downgrading bcmwl-kernel-source from 6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu1~1.1 to 6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu0.2
(Reading database ... 241561 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb ...
Removing all DKMS Modules
Done.
Unpacking bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu0.2) over (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu1~1.1) ...
Preparing to unpack bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu1~1.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu1~1.1) over (6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu0.2) ...
Preparing to unpack dkms_2.2.0.3-2ubuntu11.3_all.deb ...
Unpacking dkms (2.2.0.3-2ubuntu11.3) over (2.2.0.3-2ubuntu11.3) ...
More than one copy of package bcmwl-kernel-source has been unpacked
 in this run !  Only configuring it once.
Setting up dkms (2.2.0.3-2ubuntu11.3) ...
Setting up bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu1~1.1) ...
Loading new bcmwl-6.30.223.271+bdcom DKMS files...
Building only for 4.8.0-52-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 4.8.0-52-generic
Done.

wl:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.8.0-52-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod....

DKMS: install completed.
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Required key not available
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for shim-signed (1.27~16.04.1+0.9+1474479173.6c180c6-1ubuntu1) ...
The Secure Boot policy was already changed since last reboot; nothing to do.
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.8) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-52-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_01.bin for module i915
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add output of lspci -knn | grep Net -A3 terminal command.

Comment: @EODCraftStaff 
The output is:
Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
 Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [11ad:6605]
04:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8411B PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:5287] (rev 01)
 Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:202f]

Comment: This may help https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos - is the lspci from before or after running that command? I presume you can connect to the internet so don't need the duplicate question :)

Comment: @Wilf http://paste.ubuntu.com/24624405/